# Нахождение первого , второго и третьего максимумов в списке

Tags: python

Есть задача : Создать список из случайных чисел и найти в нём **первый**, **второй** и **третий** максимумы(три элемента в порядке убывания). Результат вывести в консоль с помощью *print*(форматный вывод *.format*). При чём сделать это нужно без использования сторонних библиотек , разве что *random* можно. В голову не приходит абсолютно ничего , подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html

Comment: Здравствуйте на Stack Overflow на русском! **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи**. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Уточните, можно ли использовать циклы для решения вашей задачи. В комментарии к одному ответу вы написали , что нельзя, а приняли другой ответ, в котором цикл как раз используется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если такой простой список (числа), что мешает его отсортировать и взять три последних?

```
import random

data = [random.randint(1, 100) for x in range(10)]

data.sort(reverse=True)

print(data[:3:])
```

Comment: А зачем второе двоеточие в слайсе?

Comment: @vp_arth, потому что ночь и я уже не соображаю :), конечно можно безболезненно убрать, но если гнаться за меньшим кол-во букв в коде, тогда можно сделать так: `data.sort() print(data[:-4:-1])`

Comment: Или `data.sort(); print(data[-3:])` У меня тут тоже за 4 утра))

Answer (score 2):

Если сортировку ещё не проходили, или смущает `O(N*logN)`, можно собрать максимумы за один проход:

```
from random import randint
randList = [randint(1, 100) for _ in range(10)]

a = b = c = float('-inf')
for el in randList:
    if el > a:
        a, b, c = el, a, b
    elif el > b:
        b, c = el, b
    elif el > c:
        c = el

# print(randList)
print('{}, {}, {}'.format(a, b, c))
```

Comment: Суть не в том, что сортировку не проходили. Я всё проходил, просто прикол задачи состоит в том, чтобы найти элементы без использования циклов и различных библиотек(random - исключение). Товарищ дал вполне вразумительный ответ. Вам за старание также спасибо.

Comment: @OwnYhide в условии про неиспользование циклов ничего не сказано. И в обоих ответах они используются